# DNS lookup to specific server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to do a query in JavaScript to a specific dns server. I looked at node.js (http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) but it just uses the local system configuration to do that. This is what I'd like to do in "dig" terms:

dig @dns.server.com fqdn.domain.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a module on npm called [`native-dns`](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns) that implements a DNS client and server in pure javascript.

Also there has been discussion off and on about adding support for custom DNS servers when querying with the built-in `dns` module. As far as I know nobody has started working on that yet (it may require changes in libuv too).

**UPDATE:** Modern versions of node now include this functionality via [`dns.setServers()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/dns.html#dns_dns_setservers_servers). For example:

```
const dns = require('dns');
dns.setServers([ 'dns.example.org' ]);
```